# Can I stop the keypress beep on my Kinesis Advantage keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, typing, ergonomics, rsi, kinesis-advantage

I'm a bit of an ergo freak and recently bought a Kinesis Advantage keyboard. The manual says to press <kbd>Program</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> but that doesn't stop the keyboard's speaker making that awful noise; in fact it changes nothing `:/`

Does anyone here have any ideas before I give in and contact Kinesis?

Answer (score 4):

In the end, I just opened her up and pulled the piezo speaker off with pliers. Works great now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following on an Advantage2 keyboard to disable the beep/click sound:

press and hold <kbd>progm</kbd> + tap <kbd>F8</kbd>

If you want it back repeat the same sequence.

source: [Advantage2 Keyboard FAQs page](https://kinesis-ergo.com/support/advantage2/)

Answer (score 2):

I have the Kinesis Advantage 2 - the instruction manual and previously accepted answer gave me no such luck. I have since learned the following:

- Toggle `KEYCLICK` status: `progm` + `F8`
- Toggle `TOGGLE TONE` status: `progm` + `shift` + `F8`

To see the current status of these toggles:

1. open any text buffer
2. `progm` + `Esc`

note: i turned off karabiner-elements (my system-level key re-mapper of choice) before switching these settings - I haven't explored what effects a remap of `Caps Lock` & `Esc` might have on this functionality

Comment: I purchased my Kinesis Advantage 2 in 2021. I also needed to press `progm` + `shift` + `F8` to disable the tone as the answer on the FAQ did not work for me either. Curiously, `progm` + `-` did disable the key press clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you remapped your <kbd>\</kbd> key? If so, you have to press the *original* location of the backslash key for it to work. (Should be between the QWERTY quote and hyphen.)

Comment: It was a long time ago now, but no. I never remapped any keys on that thing. I had reset it entirely a few times in the process of trying to get the sound to stop. I _still_ use that keyboard even now. Well worth the money!

Answer (score 1):

see How do you turn off the “beep” & “click” sounds of the keyboard? [enter link description here](https://kinesis-ergo.com/support/advantage/)

To disable the “click” noise, press and hold the Progrm key and tap the piples/backslash key (the key directly to the right of the letter “P”).

To disable the “beep” noise, press and hold the Progrm key and tap the hyphen/underscore key (the key directly below Progrm).

Comment: Advantage2 - https://kinesis-ergo.com/support/advantage2/